# How do I get all pages to adopt the user-defined browser zoom level (css/html)?

Tags: html, css, browser, zooming

I'm creating a website with multiple different pages (accessible through the nav bar).  When I zoom in on one of these pages (using ctrl +/-), the other pages don't necessarily adopt that zoom level.  So, for instance, if I make the "home" page 125% and then click onto the "contact" page, the "contact" page won't automatically be 125% as well.

How do I get all pages of my website to adopt whatever browser zoom level the user has chosen?

Comment: Are all the pages on the same domain? What browser are you using?

Comment: Zack, all the pages are in the same folder on my desktop.  I'm using Chrome and Firefox.  Interestingly, the problem doesn't seem to occur in Edge--there, all pages seem to adopt whatever browser zoom level I set.

Comment: Are you using a local web-server or just opening the HTML files in your browser?

Comment: Zack, I think the answer is that I'm just opening the HTML files in my browser, though I don't know exactly what it means to be using a local web-server (sorry, I'm an absolute beginner at this stuff).  The files are all in the same folder on my computer and are not on the web yet.  The links on my webpage all go to files in this folder.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe different browsers work differently when opening local files (using the `file://` protocol).

I assume that since the browser believes it's opening 2 different HTML files which may not have any connection it will just set the zoom-level to the default one. Some browsers may remember this setting for all files opened in the future.

When you are on the same domain however using a website or local web server (google it, read up on xampp or Node.js to simulate a real website) which uses the `http://` protocol the browser probably saves the zoom-level per domain (youtube.com, google.com etc.) so that it knows to set the zoom on all pages under that domain.